# how to stop people from sharing your website page link?

Tags: javascript, html, web, hyperlink, httpbackend

Is there a way for to make a page link  on my website non-shareable, that is, if I share a link to this page with anyone else will not be able to access it, it can only be accessed from the source

Comment: What do you mean with "the source"?

Comment: quite simply, no.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW  i mean they can open the link only on my website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a URL to the website you want it to be accessed from, you can check before you load the page if they came from it, if they didn't just close the tab or something, or display a message.

```
var oldURL = document.referrer;
if(oldURL!="YOURSITEURL.COM"){
   location.replace("WHEREVER.COM")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities (not all of which are created equal):

- **Authorization**: require users to authenticate themselves, then restrict who has access to the specific URL(s).
- **Don't use URLs**: Instead, use a single-page app that doesn't modify the URL.
- **Just be random**: Make every link point to a dynamically-generated URL that can only be visited once.

Comment: thanks for your help this ideas is what i was locking for